# Gridview is not visible in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm super new to Flutter and I have an issue when creating Gridview. 
When I call the master page is not visible. I don't know why there is a conflict - Any help?

[Here is the complete code](https://bitbucket.org/CVITUAE/flutterproject2/src/master/)

I have two pages:

**[Main]**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; import './pizza_page.dart';
import './master_page.dart' as first; import './events_page.dart' as
second; import './places_pages.dart' as third;


void main() {   runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new TestHome(),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
     "/PizzaPage": (BuildContext context) => new PizzaPage()
     },   )); }

class TestHome extends StatefulWidget {   @override   _TestHomeState
createState() => new _TestHomeState(); }

class _TestHomeState extends State<TestHome>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController controller;

  @override   void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();   }

  @override   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("NASY"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.cyan[400],
        bottom: new TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          tabs: <Widget>[
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.location_on),
            ),
            new Tab(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.event_note),
            )
          ],
         ),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
        new first.MasterPage(),
        new second.EventPage(),
        new third.PlacesPage(),
      ]),
    );   
  }
}
```

**[Master Page]**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MasterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MasterPageState createState() => new _MasterPageState();
}

class _MasterPageState extends State<MasterPage> {
  List<Container> daftarSuperhero = new List();

  var karakter = [
    {"nama": "Ipnone 5", "gambar": "iphone1.jpg"},
    {"nama": "Iphone 5s", "gambar": "iphone2.jpg"},
    {"nama": "Iphone 7", "gambar": "iphone3.jpg"},
    {"nama": "Iphone 8", "gambar": "iphone4.jpg"},
    {"nama": "Iphone X", "gambar": "iphone5.png"},
    {"nama": "Ipnone 5", "gambar": "iphone1.jpg"},
    {"nama": "Iphone 5s", "gambar": "iphone2.jpg"},
    {"nama": "Iphone 7", "gambar": "iphone3.jpg"},
    {"nama": "Iphone 8", "gambar": "iphone4.jpg"},
    {"nama": "Iphone X", "gambar": "iphone5.png"},
  ];

  _buatlist() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < karakter.length; i++) {
      final karakternya = karakter[i];
      final String gambar = karakternya["gambar"];

      daftarSuperhero.add(new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: new Card(
              child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              ),
              new Image.asset(
                "assets/products/$gambar",
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 100.0,
              ),
              new Text(
                karakternya['nama'],
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              )
            ],
          ))));
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _buatlist();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new GridView.count(
      primary: true,
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: daftarSuperhero,
    );
   }
 }
```

The main purpose of the code is to create a top navigation bar in the home screen and link it with gridview.

Comment: Why do you say there is a "conflict". Share with an [edit] any errrors you are seeing, or the reasons for your assumptions. Also, please reformat your code example to get rid of the '>' chars.

Comment: There is no error - But still, the gridview is not coming.

Comment: What have you done to solve this? What research have you done? For example, https://flutter.io/debugging/

Comment: I tried to make the masterPage as home and the gridview worked well. But once you place in the tabBarView it's not working. I guess the issue is related that i have two initState in each Class but i'm not sure.

Comment: Please don't put question content in comments. They can be removed. Clarify the question with an [edit]. _Show_ us in the question what research you have, and what some of your potentials ideas are. This is a Q&A site, so the idea is you tell us as much as you can about a situation and then ask a specific question about that situation. Reminder: make sure you've at least skimmed [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your complete code and tested it on a physical device it is working good, the only thing wrong I found was the imports:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './pizza_page.dart';
import './home_page.dart' as first;
import './events_page.dart' as second;
import './places_pages.dart' as third;
```

it should be like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pizza_page.dart';
import 'home_page.dart' as first;
import 'events_page.dart' as second;
import 'places_pages.dart' as third;
```